# tftpboot to copy kernel image from win pc to board doesnt work in dm365 based board

Tags: u-boot, tftp

I want to get **uImage** from windows pc to dm365 based board in uboot boot loader.
Ethernet phy is detected by u-boot.

```
davinci_eth_phy_detect(), ALIVE = 0x00000002
Ethernet PHY: DP83848 @ 0x01
```

For testing tftp transfer i am disconnecting pc from network and connecting it directly to board.Below configuration i use in the u-boot,

```
netmask=255.255.255.0
ethaddr=00:0C:0C:0A:FF:EC
ipaddr=192.168.178.156
serverip=192.168.178.129
gatewayip=192.168.178.1
gateway=192.168.178.1
```

When i ping pc from board ping reports "host is alive"
but i am not able to ping a device from a board.(i dont know if that is required to be done.)

Then i run "tftpd32" on windows pc, i set root/base folder appropriately.

And when i give below command request times out

```
tftpboot 0x80700000 uImage
```

When i do same procedure in my colleague's pc, there tftp works fine .
In that pc too ping works one way from board to pc, it doesnt work from pc to board.

I have added tftpd32 utility in allowed program list in windows firewall,
What could be a problem ? any suggestions ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very silly thing which i had missed, When i connect the device to the pc using ethernet cable it was detected as unknown network, and tftpd32 was present in allowed program list in windows firewall but there were three check-boxes for tftpd32(infect for every program there are 3 check-boxes).
1. Domain
2. Home/Work(private)
3. Public
and only 1st one was selected for tftpd32, i checked all three check boxes and it started working :)
It is not that great question to put it on stackoverflow but at times one doesnt find solutions to small problems easily so i am not deleting this question. Hope it helps others too. If anybody feels this is not required to keep on stackoverflow i(or admin) can delete it.

Regards, Ankur